# How to recognize SqlException where user cancelled?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, sqlclient

So, I cancelled a query using `SqlCommand.Cancel`. Sql client returned a `SqlException` with the following message:

> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any,
> should be discarded. Operation cancelled by user.

Fine by me. But, I have to gracefully deal with it since it's not a regular error which should be reported. The problem is, besides the message, there is no indicator inside the `SqlException` object that I've found which would identify that it was caused by a user cancelling the query.

I don't want to use the message itself, because it could be changed at some point or translated into another language. The Error `Number` property is `0` and `Class` property is `11`.

Answer (score 5):

For SQL Server 2008 R2 and .NET 4.0 the following properties of `SqlException` are set:

If the `SqlConnection.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors` property is set to `true`:

- `Class`: 16
- `Number`: 3204
- `Message`: The backup or restore was aborted.
  RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
  Operation cancelled by user.

If the `SqlConnection.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors` property is set to `false`:

- `Class`: 11
- `Number`: 0
- `Message`: Operation cancelled by user.